# I am having problem in sending data of a select box in a django project

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

This is my cart.js:

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for (i=0;i<updateBtns.length;i++){
updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    var productId=this.dataset.product
    var action=this.dataset.action
    console.log('productId:',productId,'Action:',action)

    console.log('user:',user)

    updateUserOrder(productId, action)
})

}

function updateUserOrder(productId,action){
    console.log('User is logged In , sending data....')

    var url = "/update_item/"

    fetch(url, {
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({'productId':productId,'action':action})
    })

    .then((response) =>{
        return response.json()
    })

    .then((data) =>{
        console.log('data:',data)
        location.reload()
    })
}
```

and this is my button:

```
<button data-product={{product.id}} data-action="remove" class="flex-c-m sizefull bg1 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4 update-cart">
                                    Added<sub>Remove</sub>
                                </button>
```

I want to apply similar kind of attributes to this selectbox:

```
<select class="selection-2" name="size" required id="sizebox">
                                {% for t in product.size.all %}
                                <option value="{{t}}" id="{{t}}">{{t}}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
```

I want to give it attributes like such that I can use javascript to send its data to my views.py:

```
def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
```

I tried fetching the selected option value and in my views.py I did size=data['size'] but got an key error. What should be the best way to send the size?any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "size"?

Comment: size is a field indicating the size of the product

Comment: in the code, where is that field?